# Revert DbContext.Savechanges in case a second DbContext.Savechanges fail

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code, which stores information in two different tables in the same method

```
public static async Task<Response> AddStockTransaction(StockTransactionsHeader header, List<StockTransactionsDetails> details)
{
    using (DataContext dbContext = new DataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.StockTransactionsHeader.Add(header);
            await  dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            int hearderID = header.TransactionHeaderID;

            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                item.TransactionHeaderID = hearderID;
            }

            dbContext.StockTransactionsDetails.AddRange(details);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new Response
            {
                IsSuccess = true
            };                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Response
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                Message = ex.Message
            };
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do, in case there is an exception in the second SaveChanges () to revert the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `SaveChanges` has been called, your datat is stored on your database. You should not call `SaveChanges` more than once in a call, unless you are willingly to persist the intermediate steps.

You can use a transaction scope to create managed transactions :

```
using (TransactionScope scope = CreateTransactionScope())
{
    DoSomthing(context);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

however, if the failure of the second part involves rolling back the first one, this means that both parts belong to the same transaction, therefore simply omitting the first `SaveChanges` would turn your code into a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

From my another [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347586/9031787): You could use [DbTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontexttransaction?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0) class.

```
private void TestTransaction()
{
    var context = new MyContext(connectionString);

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // do your stuff

            // commit changes
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            // 'undo' all changes
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```