# Make sure that call api success and save myself success

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hello I found problem when I use ASP.NET MVC with EF  and call Web API from other website(that have also use Entity Framework)
the problem is that

I want to make sure that both MVC `SaveChanges()` and Web API `SaveChanges()`   succeed both together.

Here's my dream pseudo code

```
public ActionResult Operation()
{
    Code Insert Update Delete....

    bool testMvcSaveSuccess = db.TempSaveChanges();  //it does not have this command.

    if(testMvcSaveSuccess == true)
    {
       bool isApiSuccess = CallApi(); //insert data to Other Web App


       if(isApiSuccess == true)
       {
          db.SaveChanges(); //Real Save
       }
    }
}
```

From above code, if it doesn't have `db.TempSaveChanges()`, maybe Web API will be successful, but MVC `SaveChanges()` might fail.

Comment: then why not CallAPI first, after that do mvc savechanges based on Api success or not?

Comment: @beibeizhu : call api first success  but then are you sure that mvc savechange() will success?  mvc may save fail

Comment: so u want to two operation in one transaction..data consistency problem also happens in Microservice, sorry Im not familiar with this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is nothing like `TempSaveChanges` because there is something even better: **[Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)**.

Transaction is an IDisposable (can be used in a using block) and has methods like *Commit* and *Rollback*.

Small example:

```cs
private void TestTransaction()
{
    var context = new MyContext(connectionString);

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // do CRUD stuff here 

        // here is your 'TempSaveChanges' execution
        int changesCount = context.SaveChanges();

        if (changesCount > 0)
        // changes were made
        {
            // this will do the real db changes
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            // no changes detected -> so do nothing
            // could use 'transaction.Rollback();' since there are no changes, this should not be necessary
            // using block will dispose transaction and with it all changes as well
        }
    }
}
```

I have extracted this example from my GitHub [Exercise.EntityFramework](https://github.com/MiroslavMikus/Exercise.EntityFramework) repository. Feel free to Star/Clone/Fork...

Comment: so If changesCount > 0  it would be 100% sure that transaction.Commit() will not fail right?

Comment: So far I know: SaveChanged indeed updates your database in some 'locked' manner (since we are in a transaction). This means that either everything will success or nothing will be changed. The `Commit` call will exit this locked state. `Rollback` will undo all changes and exit the lock state. Note that this transaction execution is depending on the storage technology you are currently using. For more info you could check [SQL transactions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or start the SQL profiler and check all queries

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

you need to overload the `.Savechanges` in the context class where it will be called first checked and then call the regular after.

Or create you own `TempSaveChanges()` in the context class call it then if successful call `SaveChanges` from it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is known as **atomicity**: you want several operations to either all succeed, or none of them. In the context of a database you obtain this via **transactions** (if the database supports it). In your case however, you need a transaction which spans across two disjoint systems. A general-purpose (some special cases have simpler solutions) robust implementation of such a transaction would have certain requirements on the two systems, and also require additional persistence.

Basically, you need to be able to gracefully recover from a sudden stop at any point during the sequence. Each of the databases you are using are most likely **ACID** compliant, so you can count on each DB transaction to fulfill the atomicity requirement (they either succeed or fail). Therefore, all you need to worry about is the sequence of the two DB transactions. Your requirement on the two systems is a way to determine a posteriori whether or not some operation was performed.

Example process flow:

1. Operation begins
2. Generate unique transaction ID and persist (with request data)
3. Make changes to local DB and commit
4. Call external Web API
5. Flag transaction as completed (or delete it)
6. Operation ends

Recovery:

1. Get all pending (not completed) transactions from store
2. Check if expected change to local DB was made
3. Ask Web API if expected change was made
4. If none of the changes were made or both of the changes were made then the transaction is done: delete/flag it.
5. If one of the changes was made but not the other, then either revert the change that was made (revert transaction), or perform the change that was not (resume transaction) => then delete/flag it.

Now, as you can see it quickly gets complicated, specially if "determining if changes were made" is a non-trivial operation. What is a common solution to this is to use that unique transaction ID as a means of determining which data needs attention. But at this point it gets very application-specific and depends entirely on what the specific operations are. For certain applications, you can just re-run the entire operation (since you have the entire request data stored in the transaction) in the recovery step. Some special cases do not need to persist the transaction since there are other ways of achieving the same things etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok so let's clarify things a bit.

you have an MVC app **A1**, with its own database **D1**
you then have an API, let's call it **A2** with its own database **D2**.

you want some code in **A1** which does a temp save in **D1**, then fires a call to **A2** and if the response is successful then it saves the temp data from **D1** in the right place this time.

based on your pseudo code, I would suggest you create a second table where you save your "temporary" data in **D1**. So your database has an extra table and the flow is like this:

first you save your **A1** data in that table, you then call **A2**, data gets saved in **D2**, **A1** receives the confirmation and calls a method which moves the data from the second table to where it should be.

Scenarios to consider:

1. Saving the temp data in **D1** works, but the call to **A2** fails. you now clear the orphan data with a batch job or simply call something that deletes it when the call to **A2** fails.
2. The call to **A2** succeeds and the call to **D1** fails, so now you have temp data in **D1** which has failed to move to the right table. You could add a flag to the second table against each row, which indicates that the second call to **A2** succeeded so this data needs to move in the right place, when possible. You can have a service here which runs periodically and if it finds any data with the flag set to true then it moves the data to the right place.

There are other ways to deal with scenarios like this. You could use a queue system to manage this. Each row of data becomes a message, you assign it a unique id, a GUID, that is basically a CorrelationID and it's the same in both systems. Even if one system goes down, when it comes back up the data will be saved and all is good in the world and because of the common id you can always link it up properly.